# Get faster response from server with help of MySQL and Apache

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache

I just want to know which process is fast and how (in core) flow works.

**About system:** I have a user information add and edit system inside back end of application admin.I just want to show (Read-only)  information on Android application using APIs.

**Flow:**

1. At admin side user information will add and edited.
2. After add process mysql return primary Key of user inserted data (LIKE 123) and using that primary key I make a json file (LIKE 123.json) at a particular location on same server.
3. In edit process I overwrite that file using same primary key.

---

**Here is my question:**  (2 cases)

**Case 1:** When API hit server with user primary key (LIKE 123).
(1).PHP initialized.
(2).MYsql connection create, Query fire to mysql, get data and make a json of that same data and return to API, close Mysql connection.

**Case 2:** When API hit server it just call same file which I was created at time of add or Edit with a absolute URL
**LIKE:** *www.DOMAIN.COM/json-file-path/123.json* and return back to Android.  (I amused that in this case PHP and MYSQL is not even initialized only Apache initialized )

**Now in both of cases**

**1)** Which case is fast and best ?
**2)** How  internally this (mysql, PHP, Apache) will work ?
**3)** In both of case and which one Should I use?

Comment: Case 2 is clearly fastest.... for read only access to the data... but it's slower for the admin work, because you have to create/update that file with every single change to the data. It also, probably takes more disk space on your server, and is less secure than a dynamic validation for who can access what data

Comment: So there is no simple answer to which is "best"

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks :D but i jus want to know.In case 2 is PHP initialized or just a work of apache or because I have server with very small configuration  to handle a large application ?

Comment: In case 2, you're only hitting Apache, because you're only serving a static json file, no PHP at all.... though to be honest, you don't even need apache in that case, but could use a caching proxy like varnish instead

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks, Same we are thinking to put that json file on CDN for faster response .. but i don't have idea about varnish. but I'll Google it :P